# Slow MySQL Query - how can it be speed up?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

This is edited - I have tried speeding this up but still very slow - can anyone offer anymore help please?

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.`group_ID`,
  CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) AS uname,
  u.corp_id,
  c.`corp_name`,
  u.`user_username`,
  u.location,
  (
    SELECT email 
    FROM users 
    WHERE role = 'Level 4' 
      AND location = d.location 
      AND email NOT LIKE '%manager.%' 
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS trainer,
  u.`email`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT d.title 
    ORDER BY d.title SEPARATOR ', '
  ) AS docs 
FROM regulatory d 
  LEFT JOIN users u 
    ON u.user_id = d.`group_ID` 
    AND u.`role` = 'Level 6' 
  LEFT JOIN corporations c 
    ON c.`corp_id` = u.`corp_id` 
WHERE d.`spare1` <> 'green.gif' 
  AND u.`officialjobtitle` <> 'none' 
  AND d.`date_updated` < NOW() 
  AND (u.`corp_id` IN (1)) 
GROUP BY d.`group_ID` 
ORDER BY corp_id,
  u.`location`,
  uname ;
```

Comment: Can you please format that code properly... Very hard to read

Comment: Hello - it is formatted when I look at it - thanks for replying

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the columns in your WHERE clause? Also, that check for DISTINCT address in the WHERE will sequentially scan the users table.

Comment: Interesting - thanks I will check those things!

Comment: and group by d.group_ID is complete redundant - without even looking at your data I know it won't do anything except create overhead in your query

Comment: You were absolutely right thanks!  I added indexes to the table that were referenced and not indexed and removed that DISTINCT address and it works very fast now - thanks again!

Comment: Hello again,I have tried optimising and the following query is still very slow - can anyone offer anymore help?

Comment: I have realised now that the slow part is the subselect that creates the AS trainer part, but I am not sure how to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You negate the left join from `regulatory` to `users` in the where
  clause, so use an `INNER JOIN` for those two tables
- use `INNER JOIN` on corporations if this is possible (I just don't know if it is or not)
- remove DISTINCT. You are already performing a `GROUP BY` and if that is done correctly distinct will be completely redundant (as it doesn't do anything that `GROUP BY` cannot do)
- I would try replacing the correlated subquery for `trainer` with a "derived table" that is already grouped so you don't multiply the rows
- when using `GROUP BY` in MySQL never rely on the "extension". Always specify all the fields needed to produce unique rows (like you would in almost every other SQL compliant rdbms)

Make sure you have indexes on all fields involved in the joins and if possible those used in the where clause too.

Inspect the explain plan.

**Suggested edits:**

```
SELECT
      d.`group_ID`
    , CONCAT ( u.fname , ' ' , u.lname ) AS uname
    , u.corp_id
    , c.`corp_name`
    , u.`user_username`
    , u.location
    , MAX(l4.trainer) as trainer
    , u.`email`
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.title ORDER BY d.title SEPARATOR ', ') AS docs
FROM regulatory d
INNER JOIN users u ON d.`group_ID` = u.user_id
                   AND u.`role` = 'Level 6'
LEFT JOIN corporations c ON u.`corp_id` = c.`corp_id`
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT location, MAX(email) AS trainer
        FROM users
        WHERE ROLE = 'Level 4'
            AND email NOT LIKE '%manager.%'
        GROUP BY location
        ) l4 ON d.location = l4.location
WHERE d.`spare1` <> 'green.gif'
    AND u.`officialjobtitle` <> 'none'
    AND d.`date_updated` < NOW()
    AND u.`corp_id` IN (1)
GROUP BY
      d.`group_ID`
    , u.fname
    , u.lname
    , u.corp_id
    , c.`corp_name`
    , u.`user_username`
    , u.location
    , u.`email`
ORDER BY
      corp_id
    , u.`location`
    , uname
;
```

Comment: @user2462433 you should "accept" and/or "vote up" answer if they solve your question see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer I see you have only asked 3 questions but as yet you have not accepted any either, that's not how it should work.

Comment: thank you, please do keep this in mind when using SO, voting up/down and accepting are fundamental tools for all users here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your query have little problem with line:

```
...
(
SELECT email 
FROM users 
WHERE role = 'Level 4' 
  AND location = d.location 
  AND email NOT LIKE '%manager.%' 
LIMIT 1
) AS trainer,
...
```

For each row you prepare single select. Mayby you should change that query to another join.
I wuld also recommend using explain feature to MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

Add INDEX for all the columns which you used in where condition in all database table. And it will speed up all of your queries.